# Any ideas on simplify my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dry

Any ideas how to apply DRY practice here? I know that I am repeating to much and I don't like it. But I don't know how to solve it. It would be great to simplify this unit convertor. Thanks everyone for any help.

```
$(':input').bind('keypress keydown keyup change',function(){
        var input = parseFloat($(':input[name="input"]').val())

        var output1  = '';
        var output2  = '';

        if ($("#unitSelector").val() === 'celsius'){
            output1 = ((input * 9) / 5 + 32).toFixed(5).toString();
            output2 = (input + 273.15).toFixed(5).toString();

        $(':input[name="output1"]').val(output1 + " " + "Fahrenheit");
        $(':input[name="output2"]').val(output2 + " " + "Kelvin");
        }

        if ($("#unitSelector").val() === 'fahrenheit') {
            output1 = ((input - 32) * 5 / 9).toFixed(5).toString();
            output2 = ((input + 459.67) * 5 / 9).toFixed(5).toString();

        $(':input[name="output1"]').val(output1 + " " + "Celsius");
        $(':input[name="output2"]').val(output2 + " " + "Kelvin");
        }

        if ($("#unitSelector").val() === 'kelvin') {
            output1 = (input - 273.15).toFixed(5).toString();
            output2 = (9 / 5 * (input - 273) + 32).toFixed(5).toString();

        $(':input[name="output1"]').val(output1 + " " + "Celsius");
        $(':input[name="output2"]').val(output2 + " " + "Fahrenheit");
        }
    });
```

Comment: You should post this on the code review site since there isn't really a problem with the code.  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's code review

Comment: At the very least, you should cache the selectors..  `var unitSelect = $('#unitSelector');` etc and use the variables each time you access that element.  That way jQuery isn't re-selecting it each time.

Comment: You could look at a library like Knockout which can help splitting all the jQuery from the logic, getting some separation in there. This has been a common problem with Javascript code in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a stab:

```
$(':input').bind('keypress keydown keyup change', function () {

    var input = parseFloat($(':input[name="input"]').val()),
        type = $("#unitSelector").val(),
        output1 = '',
        output2 = '',
        tag1 = 'Celsius',
        tag2 = 'Kelvin';

    switch (type) {
        case 'celsius':
            output1 = ((input * 9) / 5 + 32);
            output2 = (input + 273.15);
            tag1 = 'Fahrenheit';
            break;
        case 'fahrenheit':
            output1 = ((input - 32) * 5 / 9);
            output2 = ((input + 459.67) * 5 / 9);
            break;
        case 'kelvin':
            output1 = (input - 273.15);
            output2 = (9 / 5 * (input - 273) + 32);
            tag2 = 'Fahrenheit';
            break;
    }

    $(':input[name="output1"]').val(output1.toFixed(5).toString() + " " + tag1);
    $(':input[name="output2"]').val(output2.toFixed(5).toString() + " " + tag2);

});
```